# replace all but the last five characters of a given string into "*" and returns the new masked string

Tags: python

I have returned the correct answer by breaking up the string in the `maskString` function. However, I was wondering how to do the same with a loop? using add/join when the desired indexed is reached and new string formed. my attempt is the maskString2 function. Any ideas?? tried with `'join'` instead of `'+'`.

```py
def maskString(self, string):
    return '*'*(len(string)-5) + string[-5:]
```

```py
def maskString2(self,string):
    new_string = string[:-5]
    for i in new_string:
        new_string.replace(i, '*')
    return new_string + string[-5:]
```

Comment: Your attempt would work if you did `new_string = new_string.replace(i, '*')`, but there is an inherent flaw. Work through in your head how this would work for the word `"aardvark"`. The result is correct, but the procedure is subtly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy to understand approach:

```
def maskString(self, string):
        lst = list(string)
        for i in range(0,len(lst)-5):
            lst[i] = '*'
        s = ''.join(lst))
        return(s)
```

Assuming that the length of string is always greater than 5

Comment: this is actually the exact opposite result, but is still a good example. You should fix it up to be the correct result (`abcdefg` should be `**cdefg`, not `ab*****`)

Comment: A style nit: `l` is a bad variable name (worse than most single-letter variables) because it's easily confused with both `I` and even `1` in some contexts. Prefer `lst` for a throwaway variable name for a list.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it.